# Error while product import using Magmi

Tags: magmi

I'm not sure if anyone met the same error as me. When I'm trying to import product information into Magento via Magmi, I found the following error.

> Illegal offset type in
>   /var/www/magmi/plugins/5b5/general/attributesetimport/multi_dim_array.php
>   on line 58

Comment: I'd like to see you csv form!

Comment: Here is a part of CSV data. (our project is in Japanese)

Comment: Here is a part of CSV data. (Sorry I'm new to StackExchange, still don't know how to attache picture yet.). The 1st line is field name, and 2nd line is data

store,websites,attribute_set,type,category_ids,sku,has_options,name,meta_title, ...
admin,base,Default,simple,23,bg-325860-814091,1,Retro Vintage Airman's Rucksack,フォックスアウトドア Fox Outdoor バッグ バックパック・リュック ラップトップ【Retro Vintage Airman's Rucksack】, ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any errors in your csv form.
Could you compare this code with yours?

```
    /**
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see ArrayIterator::offsetGet()
 */
public function offsetGet($name)
{
    if (!is_array($name)) {
        return parent::offsetGet($name);
    } else {
        $key = array_shift($name);
        if (!parent::offsetExists($key)) {
            return null;
        }
        $element = parent::offsetGet($key);
        if (sizeof($name) == 0) {
            return $element;
        } else {
            if (is_a($element, 'MultiDimArray')) {
                return $element->offsetGet($name);
            } else {
                return $element;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see ArrayIterator::offsetSet()
 */
public function offsetSet($name, $value)
{
    if (!is_array($name)) {
        return parent::offsetSet($name, $value);
    } else {
        $key = array_shift($name);
        if (sizeof($name) == 0) {
            parent::offsetSet($key, $value);
        } else {
            $childArray = parent::offsetExists($key)?parent::offsetGet($key):new MultiDimArray();
            if (!is_a($childArray, 'MultiDimArray')) {
                $childArray = new MultiDimArray();
            }
            parent::offsetSet($key, $childArray);
            $childArray->offsetSet($name, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

If it is same, you remove below this code temporarily

```
if (!parent::offsetExists($key)) {
     return null;
  }
```

Comment: The code are the same after compare. I followed your comment temporary remove the code, but it still the same error.
Do you have any idea ?